# PHP Inheritance Loop

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have three classes that are structured like below. Except when it runs it loops over its self forever and spits out errors about the RandomSetting constant already being defined. If I make a method to set the $App variable and run that then any inherited classes cannot use the methods coming down like Add(). What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
abstract class start 
{
   public $var;

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->var = 1;
      define('RandomSetting', 'RandomText');
   }

   public function Add($v, $b)
   {
      return $v + $b;
   }
}

abstract class second extends start 
{
   public $foo;

   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->foo = $this->var;
   }
}

class end extends second
{
   public $App;

   public function GetTheVar()
   {
      print $this->foo;
   }
}
$bar = new end();
$bar->GetTheVar();
```

Comment: `new second()`?!? `second` is defined as abstract, so this should give an error

Comment: Your code is not valid. It's forbidden to instantiate objects of abstract classes.

Comment: But if a constant already exists, and you try to define a constant with that same name, then you will also get errors; check whether the constant is [defined](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) before trying to define it

Comment: Sorry! Miswrote that. It has been corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every new instance of class `end` will call parent constructors till the class `start`. It means that the constant 'RandomSetting' is tried to be redefined during every instance creation. That leads to a notice. You can avoid one if you check that constant already defined. See code below:

```
abstract class start 
{
   public $var;

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->var = 1;
      if (!defined('RandomSetting')) {
          define('RandomSetting', 'RandomText');
      }
   }

   public function Add($v, $b)
   {
      return $v + $b;
   }
}
```

Comment: This works it's still eternally looping through and the request never stops until the script execution time max kills it. BTW I'm using PHP 7.0.10

Comment: I've tested on PHP7.0.5 and I don't see a loop. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e69b3e62fec7e1473a91a3e405484ed498ca9cfb @lemoney

Comment: Found it! I'm on windows and group policy was the problem. Idk how but I went home and it works fine.